# Where does the start of 'Nine Billions Names of God' take place?

Tags: the-nine-billion-names-of-god

Dr Wagner is speaking to the lama about switching to computers to compile a list of the names of God. He then go on to say:

> Dr. Wagner was scarcely conscious of the faint sounds from the Manhattan
> streets far below. He was in a different world, a world of natural, not man-made, mountains

Where is Dr Wagner? Manhattan or Tibet? Is he with the lama? Are they on the phone?

Comment: *"from the Manhattan streets far below"*. He's in Manhattan

Answer (score 10):

He is in Manhattan, the lama is there to personally offer him a job. The guy leaves such a good impression that Dr Wagner is left daydreaming about Tibet for a short while, before deciding to dispatch his team.